# Percent chances something is picked

Tags: lua

Looking for a generic way to have a percent chance 1 out of N items are picked. Say you have a 50% chance to be a lion, 20% chance to be a tiger, and 30% chance to be a bear. One of these MUST be picked and the number of % chances is unlimited and unknown by the calling method and the returned value will be what you will be.

Something like:

local animal = PickAnimal([?open to the data structure passed in])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
local function pickAnimal(t)
  local p, acc = math.random(), 0
  for name, prob in pairs(t) do
    acc = acc + prob
    if p < acc then return name end
  end
  return nil
end

math.randomseed(os.time())
print(pickAnimal({lion = 0.5, tiger = 0.2, bear = 0.3}))
```